# Can connect to ubuntu server with PuTTY but can't via WinSCP

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, putty, winscp

I have just updated from 8.04 to 10.04 after such a long time I am rather excited. But since the update I am now unable to login to my server via WinSCP but a connection with PuTTY is still completely fine.

Neither are using private keys. I am just entering a username and password each time.

I do however get through to the authentication panel, where i can enter my username and password. This is where it appears to time out.

So, is there a reason why one would accept a SSH connection and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was such a bug in WinSCP before 5.0.5 version (https://winscp.net/tracker/764) and relevant discussion here (https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10266). So please check what version of WinSCP you are using. Try upgrading or downgrading to either 4.3.5 or 5.0.5 as they have no this bug.

Comment: I updated to the latest version and now indeed its all working as expected :D

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 with WinSCP 5.19.6

Adding the following lines to the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` fixed it for me

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Or use WinSCP 5.20 beta or newer, which [supports rsa-sha2](https://winscp.net/tracker/1952).

Answer (score 0):

I had "sudo su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server" in WinSCP config in advanced -> SFTP Server. Changed it back to default and I am able to connect again. Need to do some permission management I guess since this problem started only after I turned off remote root login and started to use different user.